# Forcing update of Azure function zip package during terraform deployment

Tags: azure-functions, terraform, azure-powershell, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to deploy an azure function via terraform and everytime I update code & create a new zip file and run terraform apply locally, it doesn't register the change and shows nothing to update. I thought using the hash() function inside the appsettings of the function app like below, should have been enough to detect changes to the zip folder and force the redeployment. What changes can I make to allow force update everytime the zip file changes. Also is there a way to allow force deployment of a resource regardless of any changes in terraform state?

```
resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "app" {
  name = "${var.storageblobname}"
  storage_account_name  = "${azurerm_storage_account.app.name}"
  storage_container_name = "${azurerm_storage_container.app.name}"
  type   = "Block"
  source = "./../functionapp.zip"
}



resource "azurerm_function_app" "app" {
    name                      = "${var.appname}"
    location                  = "${azurerm_resource_group.app.location}"
    resource_group_name       = "${azurerm_resource_group.app.name}"
    app_service_plan_id       = "${azurerm_app_service_plan.app.id}"
    storage_connection_string = "${azurerm_storage_account.app.primary_connection_string}"    
    identity {
        type  = "SystemAssigned"
    }
    version = "~3"

    app_settings    =   "${merge(var.appsettings,
                                map("APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY", "${azurerm_application_insights.app.instrumentation_key}",
                                    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME", "powershell",
                                    "FUNCTION_APP_EDIT_MODE",  "readonly",
                                    "https_only",  true,
                                    "HASH",  "${filebase64sha256("./../functionapp.zip")}",
                                    "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE", "https://${azurerm_storage_account.app.name}.blob.core.windows.net/${azurerm_storage_container.app.name}/${azurerm_storage_blob.app.name}${data.azurerm_storage_account_sas.app.sas}"
                                    ))}"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to deploy an azure function via terraform and everytime I
> update code & create a new zip file and run terraform apply locally,
> it doesn't register the change and shows nothing to update.

The terraform engine works based on the configuration files. If you want to reflect on the change of the zip file in the Azure function. I suggest creating a `.zip` file with a new name which is different than the old one, then the terraform plan will detect changes to the zip folder and force the redeployment.

[image]

If you are interested, you can read [Zero Downtime Updates with HashiCorp Terraform](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/zero-downtime-updates-with-terraform/).

Answer (score 0):

You can force a recreation of the blob by specifying the "content_md5"-argument . The [Terraform docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/storage_blob#content_md5) state:

> content_md5 - [...] Changing this forces a new resource to be created.

You can create a hash for the content of the ZIP-file using the `filemd5` function and assign it to this argument. It would look like this in your case:

```
resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "app" {
  name = "${var.storageblobname}"
  storage_account_name  = "${azurerm_storage_account.app.name}"
  storage_container_name = "${azurerm_storage_container.app.name}"
  type   = "Block"
  content_md5 = filemd5("./../functionapp.zip")
  source = "./../functionapp.zip"
}
```

> Also is there a way to allow force deployment of a resource regardless of any changes in terraform state?

This is possible by manually tainting a resource using Terraform CLI before running the `terraform apply` command:

```
terraform taint azurerm_storage_blob.app
```

But be careful doing this because any other member of your team could create a new plan based on that tainted object right after execution.

If you are using **Terraform v0.15.2 or above** you can also use the newly introduced `-replace` option:

```
terraform plan -replace="azurerm_storage_blob.app"
terraform apply -replace="azurerm_storage_blob.app"
```

This is a bit more safe to use because you can review your changes before any external action is taken (see also https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/taint.html).