# Updating Azure Function App through Terraform?

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-functions

I'm quite new to DevOps world. I want to know if I deploy a Function App through Terraform. Is it possible to update it later through Terraform?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

yes, we can update the azure function using terraform. you can just create the updates and override the file with a different name. with the below code you can force the recreation of files.

[image]

Here are a few blogs on updating the azure function app using terraform.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/68696619
- https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/taint
- https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/storage_blob#content_md5